# Scrapy - How to load html string into open_in_browser function

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working on some code which returns an `HTML` string (`my_html`). I want to see how this looks in a browser using https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html#open-in-browser. To do this I've tried to create a response object with body set to '`my_html`'. I've tried a bunch of things including:

```
new_response = TextResponse(body=my_html)
open_in_browser(new_response)
```

based on the response class (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#response-objects). I'm getting:

```
new_response = TextResponse(body=my_html)
  File "c:\scrapy\http\response\text.py", line 27, in __init__
    super(TextResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: *...takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)* WTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TextResponse` expects a URL as first argument](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse):

```
>>> scrapy.http.TextResponse('http://www.example.com')
<200 http://www.example.com>
>>>
```

If you want to pass a body, you still need a URL as first argument:

```
>>> scrapy.http.TextResponse(body='<html><body>Oh yeah!</body></html>')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy12/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/response/text.py", line 27, in __init__
    super(TextResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
>>> scrapy.http.TextResponse('http://www.example.com', body='<html><body>Oh yeah!</body></html>')
<200 http://www.example.com>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to be better about checking the docs and so your point about the url being needed (class scrapy.http.Response(url[, status=200, headers=None, body=b'', flags=None, request=None])) is something for me to look for in future.

Answer (score 1):

Your error seems to be with the `TextResponse` initialization, [according to the docs,](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#textresponse-objects) you need to initialize it with a URL, `TextResponse("http://www.expample.com")` should do it.

It looks like you are looking at the `Response` object docs and trying to use `TextResponse` like you would `Response`, by the looks of your optional argument and link to the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.