# Scrapy opening html in editor , not browser

Tags: python, scrapy

[image]

I am working on some code which returns an `HTML` string (`my_html`). I want to see how this looks in a browser using https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html#open-in-browser.  I just asked a question on this ([Scrapy - How to load html string into open_in_browser function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40109782/scrapy-how-to-load-html-string-into-open-in-browser-function)) and the answers have shown me how to load the string into the 'open_in_browser object'

```
headers = {
        'accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': "1",
        'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36",

        'referer': "http://civilinquiry.jud.ct.gov/GetDocket.aspx",
        'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate, sdch",
        'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.8",
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
            }

    new_response = TextResponse('https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#response-objects', headers=headers, body='<html><body>Oh yeah!</body></html>')
    open_in_browser(new_response)
```

However now I'm seeing the text open up in notepad rather than the browser (on my windows system) making me think that the system thinks this is a text string not html (even though it has an outer html tag):

How can I get this working?

edit:

I changed the code to

```
new_response = Response('https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#response-objects', headers=headers, body='<html><body>Oh yeah!</body></html>')
```

Now getting:

```
TypeError: Unsupported response type: Response
```

edit2:

I realized that in my version of scrapy (1.1) the source is:

```
def open_in_browser(response, _openfunc=webbrowser.open):
    """Open the given response in a local web browser, populating the <base>
    tag for external links to work
    """
    from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse, TextResponse
    # XXX: this implementation is a bit dirty and could be improved
    body = response.body
    if isinstance(response, HtmlResponse):
        if b'<base' not in body:
            repl = '<head><base href="%s">' % response.url
            body = body.replace(b'<head>', to_bytes(repl))
        ext = '.html'
    elif isinstance(response, TextResponse):
        ext = '.txt'
    else:
        raise TypeError("Unsupported response type: %s" %
                        response.__class__.__name__)
    fd, fname = tempfile.mkstemp(ext)
    os.write(fd, body)
    os.close(fd)
    return _openfunc("file://%s" % fname)
```

I changed Response to HTMLresponse and it started working. Thank you

Comment: Looks like it may depend on the file extension association for `.html` files. You can try changing the file association in Windows to associate `.html` to your browser application instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at how the [`open_in_browser()`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/129421c7e31b89b9b0f9c5f7d8ae59e47df36091/scrapy/utils/response.py#L63) function is defined:

```
if isinstance(response, HtmlResponse):
    if b'<base' not in body:
        repl = '<head><base href="%s">' % response.url
        body = body.replace(b'<head>', to_bytes(repl))
    ext = '.html'
elif isinstance(response, TextResponse):
    ext = '.txt'
else:
    raise TypeError("Unsupported response type: %s" %
                    response.__class__.__name__)
```

It would create a `.txt` file if it is getting a `TextResponse` - that's why you see the notepad opening the file with your HTML inside.

Instead, you need to initialize the regular [`scrapy.Response`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response) object and pass it to `open_in_browser()`.

Or, you can create the temp HTML file with the desired contents manually and then using the `file://` protocol open it in a default browser through the [`webbrowser.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Python 2.7

```
open_in_browser(scrapy.http.HtmlResponse(url = '', body = bytes(response.body)))
```

- I tried without the *url* and without transforming the *response.body* into bytes, but throws errors in both cases.
- If you use scrapy.http.Response instead of scrapy.http.HtmlResponse it also complaints of unsupported response type